# Check total VM utilization(in hours)

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, utilization

We have purchased Azure services on hourly basis(Roughly 300 hours for a month).
Where/How we can check total VM utilization?
Precisely, Total number of hours used by the team.

We tried to explore some of the options on azure portal but nowhere it's showing total VM utilization.

Answer (score 4):

You can download your usage report in Cost Management + Billing and check the hours used for running compute resources of your VMs. This link should help: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/vm-usage

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure Cost Management to view the amount you are spening on virtual machine hours. You can break this down by various metrics, resource group, tags, size etc.